# Is it "einige vor den Kopf stoßen" or "einigen vor den Kopf stoßen"?

Tags: grammar, idiom, grammatical-case

The whole sentence is:

> Mit dem Glauben an einen hinsichtlich der Präzision und Allmächtigkeit abgeschwächten Laplace'schen Dämon scheint man immer wieder einige(n?) Leuten vor den Kopf zu stoßen

I'm not sure what case to use here.

Comment: It should be "einige Leute" then, not "einige Leuten", like your sentence seems to suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laut http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kopf heißt es

> - jemanden vor den Kopf stoßen (umgangssprachlich; jemanden in plumper
>     Weise kränken, verletzen)

somit müsste "einige" richtig sein.

Answer (score 2):

"vor den Kopf stoßen" needs the 4th case = Akkusativ. Therefore it's "einige". "einigen" would be the 3rd case = Dativ.